# Calculate days between date and today in PHP

Tags: php, date-arithmetic

If I have a given date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, how can I calculate the difference in days to the current date ?

I just want to check whether this date is more than one week (7 days) old compared to the current date.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
$from = strtotime('2013-11-01');
$today = time();
$difference = $today - $from;
echo floor($difference / 86400);  // (60 * 60 * 24)
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-11-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-11-15');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a');
```